How do I make an icon into a hyperlink without creating a clickable area elsewhere?
I am trying to add icons to lead to social media pages on my website. Whenever I try to do it the 'normal' way using  tags it works but also leaves an entire bar of blank space on the page as a clickable link. I want to know how to get rid of that area and really just have the icon be clickable.
I have not found any content describing this so I am unsure of what to try. I've added color to the  tags to highlight the area that it created. I have tried setting 'pointer-events' to none but that just completely disables the link.
<<div id="footer">
    <hr>
    <a style="background-color: black;"    href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i>
    </a>
    <a style="background-color: blue;" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i>
    </a>
</div>

Image showing the clickable area created by the  tags

I have difficulty reproducing what you show and described with to code in your question. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/xxvEaWV

@asportnoy Please do not change the code in this question again. You might think it is wrong now but changing it doesn't improve the question.

I did just look at how it displayed on your end. It looks how it should there. I'll review my code to see if I did something wrong.

@CollenRowe did you manage to solve your problem? If so, consider adding an answer detailing your solution so others might have access to the resource. If you still need help, let us know what's going on so we can further assist :)
